# How to create subscriber in a publisher

Tags: ros, node, topic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to create a node that will publish a topic but before that subscribes to listen to another topic.  I want to rostopic pub /my_topic_cg std_gs/String "GO" ,and when the listener gets the "GO" published another topic which would print "The race has started" for example.  How can i manage this? ive looked into it in the tutorial but could not get a answer.  Also can i publish a number instead of a string, how can I do it in cpp?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/85936/how-to-create-subscriber-in-a-publisher/) by [ctguell](https://answers.ros.org/users/5132/ctguell/) on ROS Answers with karma: 63 on 2013-10-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes you can do that.  I suggest you go through [all the ROS Tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials). ([This one](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28c%2B%2B%29) will help you, but you should go through all of them before as they are cumulative.)

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-10-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0